# Setting header based on client certificate

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, reverse-proxy

I have Apache running as a reverse proxy for an internal server.  Users hitting the proxy are required to use client certificates.  On the internal server, there is a web application that can use an HTTP header for authenticating users.  I would like to have the proxy provide that header based on the client certificate.

The header value is the user's id.  Ideally I would have a text file mapping user id to certificate.  Near as I can tell, I need `RewriteMap` but for headers.

```
# Somehow lookup USERID given SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
RequestHeader set X-User-ID %{USERID}
```

I'd like to avoid a whole bunch of `SetEnvIf`s requiring server restarts to change, e.g.:

```
SetEnvIf SSL_CLIENT_S_DN [User 1's SSL_CLIENT_S_DN] USERID=12
SetEnvIf SSL_CLIENT_S_DN [User 2's SSL_CLIENT_S_DN] USERID=34
SetEnvIf SSL_CLIENT_S_DN [User 3's SSL_CLIENT_S_DN] USERID=56
...
```

Is there a good way I can avoid the users from needing to essentially authenticate twice?

Comment: Can you change the web application to not use a number-id as "USERID" but the client certificate DN?

Comment: It's a third-party application that is unfortunately closed source.

Comment: Programamtically it is clear, what has to happen.  But I do not think that apache is capable to do such a thing out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you need, but please correct me if I'm wrong. This requires a 3 stage approach.

You use a `RewriteCond` with  a `RewriteMap` to map the `SSL_CLIENT_S_DN` to a `USERID`, a `RewriteRule` to set an environment variable and then a `RequestHeader` directive to set a header based on the environment variable. This should cause the header to be passed onto the internal server normally.

Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Define a RewriteMap for DN to user id
RewriteMap dntouserid "txt:/path/to/dntouserid.txt"
# Test if we have something in the map for a the current DN
RewriteCond  ${dntouserid:%{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}} (.+)
# Set environment variable based on that mapping. %1 comes from the RewriteCond
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MYUSER:%1]
# Set header to that environment variable
RequestHeader set X-User-ID %{MYUSER}e
```

And then your map contains lines like:

```
DN_OF_USER1 12
DN_OF_USER2 34
DN_OF_USER3 56
```

If the DN contains spaces you will have to use an external program to do the map rather than a plain text file (it might work for other map types, but I've not tried myself).